# Spring load file from project folder for unit test

Tags: java, spring, file, url

I want to load an `xsd` file which is located at `../OtherContent/WEB-INF/spring/some-dir/filename.xsd`, where `OtherContent` folder is located in the same folder as my `src` folder. I have tried the following -

```
String path = "/OtherContent/WEB-INF/spring/some-dir/filename.xsd";
URL url = MyClass.class.getResource(path);
```

The url object remains `null`. How do I load this file into a `URL` object ?

Comment: You do this processing from a server or it is just a local test ?

Comment: this for a unit test

Comment: OtherContent/WEB-INF/spring/some-dir/filename.xsd seems not to be in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me.

xsi:schemaLocation=
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
             classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
             classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-context-3.0.xsd"